# How can I calibrate my printer using the LaTeX test page?

Tags: printing, latex, hplip

I am trying to print a LaTeX compiled document but my printer doesn't print the top part. It seems that the top part is outside of the printing range.

To debug this problem I have printed the LaTeX test page (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/testpage.tex) and it turns out that my printer is placing the content about 4.5mm closer to the top of the page than it should.

How can I calibrate my printer/driver so that it will place the content where it is supposed to go? I am using an HP OfficetJet 7300 printer with hplip.

The `hp-linefeedcal` application is not available for this printer.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23314/how-to-remove-1-inch-paddings-without-using-hoffset-and-voffset could help you. Although I did remember that there should be a global parameter somewhere...

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, I had hoped to find a solution that avoids touching the actual LaTeX document as this is already using a custom class for formatting.

Comment: Which LaTeX are you using (pdflatex, latex, xelatex)?... I an sure there is an option to dvips (if you're using plain LaTeX) to offset the page. Not sure about pdflatex and the others.

Comment: I tried both `latex` and `pdflatex` with similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the (old) `.tex`->`.dvi`->`.ps` way to produce your postscript, you can use the follow trick:

```
latex myfile.tex
dvips -O0mm,4.5mm myfile.dvi
```

There are printer configuration files in the system; probably if you edit `/usr/share/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/config.ps` and introduce the offset here that will be applied automatically (this is the "default printer" that uses `dvips` when creating a file). Or you can create an ad-hoc printer specification to use with the `dvips` `-P` option. Remenber to run `sudo texconfig rehash` if you add a new file. (Notice: I have not tested this. I will edit this answer to a less terse one if I can find time to test...)

If you use direct PDF output, I am not sure. I will add to this answer if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks! While this doesn't fix the underlying problem with the printer driver it is at least a workaround that I can use until I find a better solution.

Comment: The other path to explore (if the offset is here with all documents, not only LaTeX ones) is to look at your `.ppd` printer file. It should  be in `/etc/cups/ppd` --- There is a `*HWMargins:` directive that looks promising.